# Segmentation fault 11 - Not sure how to make a map dynamic memory allocating

Tags: dictionary, dynamic-memory-allocation

**For full code -->**, https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Documents/ProjectC%2B%2B/Pandemic3.cpp?w=AAAEs2dZglONv5y-pI9Y3iM-AqYGIKfHJ_A7qTep7bpqew
I have been compiling and running this code in terminal using g++.

Basically I am storing object Country with key Codes, which is the dial code of the country - it gives me segmentation fault 11 after printing the contents of the map.

Keziahs-MacBook-Pro:ProjectC++ keziahwain$ ./a.out
Please enter data for a country.

Would you like to do this from a file (f), or manually(m)?

f

Enter file name, with .txt after it

data.txt

Would you like to enter data for another country? (Y or N)

N

Printing countries stored in map:

Dial code: 11, country:

---

City: Finland

Population: 1000

Birth Rate:1

Death Rate:1

Dialling code:11

---

Segmentation fault: 11

I assume/think i need to dynamically allocate memory either for the map, or for the object in the map, but I dont really know how to write the correct syntax. Already tried changing the 'typedef map' to 'typedef *map', the 'dialcode codes;' to 'dialcode *codes = new dialcode' - these just cause more errors. Any help?

Comment: Please just paste here the problematic lines. Not the whole thing, just what is needed.

Comment: typedef map <int, Country> dialcode; 

Country searchDatabase (dialcode &codes, int codeSearch) {
 dialcode::iterator dialCodesIter; 
 dialCodesIter = codes.find(codeSearch); 
 
 if(dialCodesIter != codes.end())
  {cout <<"Found country for dial code " << codeSearch << " = " <<dialCodesIter->second << endl; }
 else
  {cout <<"Sorry, code " << codeSearch << " is not in database"<<endl;}
  return dialCodesIter->second;
}

Comment: dialcode codes;    is the map initialiser I've used

argh formatting looks awful, let me know if you want it sorted